# R - how to generate all possible formulae

Tags: r, formula

I have a dataframe in `R` with a dependent tally variable `Freq` and explanatory variables `Y1`,`Y2`,...,`Ym`. 
I need to estimate all possible loglinear models including (`Y1`,...,`Ym`) starting from the model with no interactions to one with all possible interactions.
That is, with `m=3` variables, from the simplest `Freq ~ Y1+Y2+Y3`
to the saturated `Freq ~ ( Y1+Y2+Y3 )^3`

in addition, I need the hierarchical models only, that is, if a 2-way interaction `Y2:Y3` is not included, higher order interactions as `Y1:Y2:Y3` or `Y2:Y3:Y4` should not be included in that model. 
So, in the above example, 7 models remain:
`Y1*Y2+Y3`,  `Y1*Y3+Y2`,  `Y1+Y2*Y3`,
`Y1*Y2+Y1*Y3`, `Y1*Y2+Y2*Y3`, `Y1*Y3+Y2*Y3`, 
`(Y1+Y2+Y3)^2`

`Y1`,...,`Ym` are 0/1 variables so it doesn't matter if they are coded as factor or numeric.

I am thinking to some recursive function manipulating strings to generate all formulae, and, for each formula, estimate the model via `loglin` or `glm` poisson. However, specific packages to estimate all possible (hierarchical) loglinear models are welcome, as long as I can retrieve the output (coefficient estimates) for each fitted model.

I am aware that the number of models can be huge, but I need an exhaustive search, not an efficient model selection.

Comment: You are probably looking for `dredge` in package MuMIn.

Comment: @Roland Thank you! It works and gives hierarchical models by default. If you write an answer I'll be happy to accept it